# What is the format for credentials in ServiceStacks JsonServiceClient?

Tags: typescript, servicestack

I'm attempting to use ServiceStack's typescript JsonServiceClient, and it works fine with routes that don't require authentication, but I can't find any documentation on how to use it with authenticated routes.

I'm using basic authentication, and I can get it work if I manually set the authorization header, but I see that the JsonServiceClient has credentials property that is a string.

What format should that credentials string be in to use basic auth ( or any other auth providers) and how do I ensure the basic auth header is sent on every request?

I know I shouldn't have to set the authorization header manually like a caveman.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you've registered the `CredentialsAuthProvider` you can authenticate with a normal Web Service Request, e.g:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl);
client.Post(new Authenticate {
    provider = "credentials",
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password,
    RememberMe = true,
});
```

If successful (i.e. doesn't throw) the ServiceClient will be populated with [ServiceStack's Session Cookies](http://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#cookie-session-ids) allowing it to make authenticated requests.

If you have HTTP Basic Auth enabled, i.e. registered the `BasicAuthProvider` then you can use the built-in Username/Password properties to send HTTP Basic Auth credentials with each request, i.e:

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient(baseUrl) {
    UserName = userName,
    Password = password
};
```

Some other options for authenticating with the Service Client is to [specify an API Key](http://docs.servicestack.net/api-key-authprovider#interoperable) if you've registered the `ApiKeyAuthProvider` or [specifying a JWT Token](http://docs.servicestack.net/jwt-authprovider#sending-jwt-with-service-clients) if using a `JwtAuthProvider`.

Comment: It looks like the typescript definitions for the JsonServiceClient may be incomplete. There are no UserName or Password properties defined in the JsonServiceClient class exported in the typecript definition file.

Comment: @on3al ok sorry, just see that you meant TypeScript - there's no UserName / Password fields on TypeScript's `JsonServiceClient` I'll look at adding it in next version. You can send `Authenticate` Request DTO or use `client.headers` to send the [Authorization Basic ${base64(user:pass)}](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication)

Comment: @on3al FYI I've added support for [HTTP Basic Auth](https://github.com/ServiceStack/servicestack-client/commit/3ed0e60226488e06fea7cbde5dcd9c776dc1b9b6)  which is now published on npm but still need to wait for [typings to merge this PR](https://github.com/typings/registry/pull/913) before typings will install the latest version containing the `userName`, `password` and alternative `setCredentials()` APIs.